# Simple LINQ query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics

I have a collection like this

```
 List<int> {1,15,17,8,3};
```

how to get a flat string like "1-15-17-8-3" through LINQ query?

thank you

Comment: LINQ's Aggregate method should do this, but I don't know the C# lambda syntax well enough to test it out.

Comment: I posted a solution using Aggregate further down.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

something like...

```
string mystring = string.Join("-", yourlist.Select( o => o.toString()).toArray()));
```

(Edit: Now its tested, and works fine)

Comment: If that works...I like it.  Very short, sweet, and to the point!

Comment: This is the best answer. Note though, that the Join method used here has nothing to do with LINQ, it's a very useful method from the good old VB6 days....

Comment: Sure, the linq bit is just the conversion of the Int list to a string array via a select and a toArray()

Comment: True, but it doesn't answer how to do this through LINQ.  With strings, I definitely would use this or StringBuilder, but seeing how this would be done the LINQ way would be a great introduction to using Aggregate (my solution using Aggregate is posted further down)

Answer (score 1):

You can write an extension method and then call .ToString("-") on your IEnumerable object type as shown here:

```
int[] intArray = { 1, 2, 3 };
Console.WriteLine(intArray.ToString(","));
// output 1,2,3

List<string> list = new List<string>{"a","b","c"};
Console.WriteLine(intArray.ToString("|"));
// output a|b|c
```

Examples of extension method implementation are here:

http://coolthingoftheday.blogspot.com/2008/09/todelimitedstring-using-linq-and.html
http://www.codemeit.com/linq/c-array-delimited-tostring.html

Answer (score 1):

Use Enumerable.Aggregate like so:

```
var intList = new[] {1,15,17,8,3};

string result = intList.Aggregate(string.Empty, (str, nextInt) => str + nextInt + "-");
```

This is the standard "LINQy" way of doing it - what you're wanting is the aggregate.  You would use the same concept if you were coding in another language, say Python, where you would use reduce().

EDIT:
That will get you "1-15-17-8-3-".  You can lop off the last character to get what you're describing, and you can do that inside of Aggregate(), if you'd like:

```
string result = intList.Aggregate(string.Empty, (str, nextInt) => str + nextInt + "-", str => str.Substring(0, str.Length - 1));
```

The first argument is the *seed*, the second is function that will perform the aggregation, and the third argument is your *selector* - it allows you to make a final change to the aggregated value - as an example, your aggregate could be a numeric value and you want return the value as a formatted string.

HTH,

-Charles

Comment: Actually I think this is what you wanted...
myList.Select(o => o.ToString()).Aggregate((s1,s2) => s1 + "-" + s2);

Comment: Aggregate is a good answer, but I personally find its harder to understand than a simple string.join() (just my own personal pref)

Comment: I second Tim J, thats how I prefer to do it.

Comment: If the list contains many elements then all those string concatenations will affect the performance. You could use a StringBuilder for the accumulator instead.

Comment: (By the way, your second version will throw an exception if the list is empty.)

Comment: @Tim: Nope `string result = intList.Aggregate(string.Empty, (str, nextInt) => str + nextInt + "-");` is correct. str is the "running total" - what's been aggregated thus far.

Comment: @Luke: Good catch. You could check before hand, or use something like `str.Length - 1 > 0 ? : str.Length - 1 : 0` - but that's pretty ugly.

Comment: @Charles: Or, slightly less ugly: `Math.Max(str.Length - 1, 0)`

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach(int i in collection)
{
    sb.Append(i.ToString() + "-");
}

string result = sb.ToString().SubString(0,sb.ToString().ToCharArray().Length - 2);
```

Something like this perhaps (off the top of my head that is!).

Answer (score 0):

The best answer is [given by Tim J](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095282/simple-linq-query/1095301#1095301).

If, however, you wanted a pure LINQ solution then try something like this (much more typing, and much less readable than Tim J's answer):

```
string yourString = yourList.Aggregate
    (
        new StringBuilder(),
        (sb, x) => sb.Append(x).Append("-"),
        sb => (sb.Length > 0) ? sb.ToString(0, sb.Length - 1) : ""
    );
```

*(This is a variation on [Charles's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095282/simple-linq-query/1095406#1095406), but uses a `StringBuilder` rather than string concatenation.)*